# How to config SMTP Settings in Sentry?

Tags: docker, smtp, docker-compose, sentry

How to config SMTP Settings in `Sentry`?

I set my SMTP mail-server configuration on `onpremise/config.yml`, then I did as follows:

`sudo docker-compose run --rm web upgrade`
`sudo docker-compose up -d` (before that, I removed previous consider containers)

But in Sentry mail setting panel not appeared my SMTP configs:

[image: sentry SMTP setting]

---

**NOTE**: I'm using [onpremise](https://github.com/getsentry/onpremise) sentry docker package.

What should I do?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) You are offtopic here as your question is not related to programming, see instead [su] or [sf]. 2) Avoid posting images, try to put details as text.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek `Sentry` is a popular logging tracker that is compatible with many languages and frameworks. sentry is an opensource application that is written with python / django. This question maybe need to changing in python code or config script or docker flow. This question is not related to the `super user` or `server fault` discussion.This question is closer to the `stackoverflow` than them is.

Comment: Like you write yourself in title: it is a **configuration** problem, not a programming one. You are off-topic here.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Read the question full. this question related on `sentry`, `docker`, maybe `python`. these are related more closer to `stackoverflow` not `server fault` or any things else.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Do you know any the ask `configuration` discussion site?!

Comment: I read your question. It starts with: "How to config SMTP Settings in Sentry". This is not a programming question, it is a question about configuring Sentry. Hence you are off-topic here.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I asked a question about sentry smtp configs, that it is related on programming technologies and method (such as `python`, `smtp`, `docker`, `django`), so then this question is true and belongs to this one (`stackoverflow`).

Comment: You can repeat things at nauseam, but it remains that configuration is not programming. If you do not see the difference, I will stop arguing with you as this is not useful. And you can put as many keywords related to programming you like, that does not change anything.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek You can repeat things at nauseam, but this question is correct.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek  I think you should focus on whole question instead of the title only.

Comment: @JohnXiao What is your point exactly 6 months later? Neither in title **nor in body** is anything related to programming in this question.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Problem solved:

I updated my Sentry version from 8.22.0 to 9.0.0 with Dockerfile and configure config.yml file as following:

### A piece of config.yml on [onpremise](https://github.com/getsentry/onpremise) package:

```
###############
# Mail Server #
###############

mail.backend: 'smtp'  # Use dummy if you want to disable email entirely
mail.host: 'smtp.gmail.com'
mail.port: 587
mail.username: 'account@gmail.com'
mail.password: '********'
mail.use-tls: true
# The email address to send on behalf of
mail.from: 'account@gmail.com'
```

### Dockerfile:

```
FROM sentry:9.0-onbuild
```

Or you can do `$ git pull` in [onpremise](https://github.com/getsentry/onpremise) path (to get latest changes).

### Finally:

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose run --rm web upgrade
docker-compose up -d
```

---

Comment: if anyone is wondering where this config file is in your docker setup, just cd into ./sentry of your setup and there you will find it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I was also having this issue. Solved it by following this steps.

Comment: This solution works when there is a newer version to upgrade to. For the case where we are still using the same version, we can just use `docker-compose restart` after modifying `config.yml`.

Answer (score 10):

**If you are running Docker check your docker-compose.yml**

Most likely you overwrite `SENTRY_EMAIL_HOST` variable and other variables like the following:

```
SENTRY_EMAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com 
SENTRY_EMAIL_PORT=587 
SENTRY_EMAIL_PASSWORD={pass} 
SENTRY_EMAIL_USER={email} 
SENTRY_EMAIL_USE_TLS=true 
SENTRY_SERVER_EMAIL={email}
```

https://github.com/getsentry/onpremise/blob/master/docker-compose.yml#L24

Comment: Did you try it with a true result? This needs to user, pass, smtp and etc

Comment: Yes, I did it yesterday. It works for me.

Variables from my .ENV file:
SENTRY_EMAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
SENTRY_EMAIL_PORT=587
SENTRY_EMAIL_PASSWORD={pass}
SENTRY_EMAIL_USER={email}
SENTRY_EMAIL_USE_TLS=true
SENTRY_SERVER_EMAIL={email}

Comment: OK, +1, I updated your answer through the content of your comments, I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 6):

I had to rebuild all containers by running `docker-compose up --build -d` to get sentry pick up the change. Maybe rebuilding `worker` alone is enough but it doesn't take long to rebuild everything anyway.

The reason is that `worker` container reads from a copy of the `config.yml`. The rebuild process will copy the changed `config.yml` into `worker` container again.

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick for me after changing `config.yml` file.

Answer (score 4):

You need add some configurations in [config.yml](https://github.com/getsentry/onpremise/blob/master/config.yml).

for example:

```
mail.host: 'smtp.gmail.com'
mail.port: 465
mail.username: 'sentry.server'
mail.password: 'Pa5$w0rD'
mail.use-tls: true
mail.from: 'sentry.server@gmail.com'
```

Comment: I wrote in my question that I've configured `config.yml` before. but not any change in `sentry SMTP setting`.

Comment: You don't forget step `docker-compose run --rm web upgrade` ? I repeat all way, just now, and for me all work excellent.

Comment: yes, I do that: `docker-compose run --rm web upgrade` then `docker-compose up -d` but not any changes appear.

Answer (score 2):

None of above works for me. The only thing worked is: modify `config.yml` file and run `docker-compose restart`, then everything works.